# How to Fit the layout to the screen size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout, swiftui

[image]

I'm just starting to learn Swift.

The picture above is the screen I made using VStack and HStack.

But I want to place the button or text wherever I want.

[image]

This picture is a picture that I have arranged by adjusting the size using a frame.

However, when the resolution is changed, there is a problem that the button or text goes over the screen.

I want to keep this arrangement and do it automatically apply at various iPhone resolutions.

```
VStack {
        HStack {
            Text("Hello")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.black)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
        VStack {
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("ID")
                        .padding()
                    Text("PW")
                        .padding()
                }
                
                VStack {
                    TextField("ID", text: $ID)
                        .padding()
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    SecureField("password", text: $password)
                        .padding()
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                }
            }
            
        }
        VStack {
            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Action@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                Text("Login")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.green.cornerRadius(18))
            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Action@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                Text("Sign up")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.red.cornerRadius(18))
        }
    }
```

The source code is very inexperienced.

I would appreciate if you can let me know if this is the correct way to write the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)`. this makes `View`'s size maximize to their container.

Plus, use `.background()` modifier on `Text` not `Button`.

If you use `.background()` on `Button` like your codes, `Button` acts only for text area.

```
VStack {
    Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Action@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
        Text("Login")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .background(Color.green.cornerRadius(18)) 
    }
    .padding()

    Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Action@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
        Text("Sign up")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .background(Color.red.cornerRadius(18))
    }
    .padding()
}
```